# How to prove that a set spans a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, span

How do we prove that a set of vectors span a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

(This is not the question I am asking for help with! This is an example of the method my teacher has given us to show that a set spans something!) For instance, to prove that the set $B = \{2, x-1, x^2+1\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}_2[x]$, my teacher has had us prove the following statement
$$\exists w,y,z \in \mathbb{R}\ \mbox{such that}\  w*2+ y*(x-1) +z*(x^2+1) = ax^2 + bx + c.$$
Instead of $ax^2 + bx + c$, what would we use for a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

**Edit:**  To be more clear, the plane we have is $ax + by + cz=0$. How would I show that a set spans that?

Comment: $ax^2+bx+c$ is the generic form of a second degree polynomial. Why would you want a "different" generic form?

Comment: Note: $\{1,x,x^{2}\}$ forms a basis for the space. So any element in the space can be written as some linear combination: $ax^{2} + bx + c$.

Comment: I don't want a different generic form of a second degree polynomial. That was just an example for how my teacher is having us prove that a set spans something. I would like to know what form of a plane I could use there? For instance, the plane we have is ax + by + cz=0. How would I show that a set spans that?

Comment: What does $\mathbb{R}_2[x]$ mean? How is that related to showing a set of vectors spans a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Generally, a plane is of the form $\{x | \langle n, x \rangle = \alpha \}$, where $n$ is a normal to the plane.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}_2[x]$ is the set of all polynomials that have a degree of 2 or less. However, it isn't really related. That was just an example of the process we have been using to show that a set of something spans something.

Comment: We have never used that form though copper.hat. Our form of a vector space is always in point-normal form or standard form.

Comment: A set of vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ spans a plane if and only if any subset of three or more vectors is linearly dependent, and at least two are linearly independent. The simple way to decide this is to throw them into a matrix and row reduce. If you have 2 pivots, the set spans a plane.

Comment: What you are trying to do is to show that any polynomial for example 3 _x^2_ + 222 _x_ - 188 can be written as a linear combination of the 3 polynomials in _B_ . But it's impossible to test an infinity of polynomials even if you tried till tomorrow morning. So the trick is to use a general polynomial: _a_ , _b_ and _c_ are any number. Then if you can find the values of _w_ , _y_ and _z_ , you have shown that any polynomial can be expressed as linear combination of the elements in _B_ . Maybe you could start with a numeric example, for example 3 _x^2_ + 2 _x_ + 1 and then try the general case.

Comment: @BernardMassé  That's a good,straightforward way to approach the problem.

Comment: I don't want to prove it for $\mathbb{R}_2[x]$ though. I want to prove it for $ax+by+cz=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane

$$ ax+by+cz=0$$

is the nullspace of the matrix

$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}a & b & c\end{matrix}\right]$$

Given an arbitrary set of vectors $S$, you can determine that they span the above plane by checking:

1. All of the vectors are in the nullspace of the matrix. That is $Av=0$ for all $v\in S$
2. $S$ contains at least two linearly independent vectors

Comment: Bingo.There you go.

Answer (score 0):

David's already answered this in a neat way above, but let me try to fill some of the conceptual gaps:

The idea is: "using linear combinations of the elements in my set, can I reach *every* element of my space?". Your teacher has simply noted that *every* element of your space can be written uniquely as $ax^2 + bx + c$ for some $a, b, c$. In effect, your teacher is taking a nice basis you already *know*, $\{1, x, x^2\}$, and relating your new prospective spanning set to it.

If you happen to know a basis for your plane, e.g. $\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1\\3\\5 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2\\-1\\0 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$, then you can use that in the same way: every element of your plane can be written uniquely in the form $r \begin{pmatrix} 1\\3\\5 \end{pmatrix} + s\begin{pmatrix} 2\\-1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$, so it suffices to show that you can make everything of that form out of your prospective spanning set.

If you don't know a basis for your plane, you can always find one. I would wager that $\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} b\\-a\\0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0\\c\\-b \end{pmatrix} \right\}$ is probably a basis for your plane - to show this, it suffices to check that these two vectors are linearly independent (and they will automatically be spanning by a dimension count). (N.B. of course, you need to be careful if $b = 0$ here, but I'm sure you can see how to fix it if this is the case.)

If you don't know a basis for your plane, and writing one down explicitly looks like a bit of a thankless task, this is where David's answer comes in. It's essentially a way of doing the same thing without the need to pick a basis.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful explanation! The reason I'm actually trying to prove that a set spans that plane is because I'm trying to prove that a set (the set {(b,-a,0),(0,c,-b)} actually haha) is a basis of the plane and thus prove that the dimension of the plane is 2!

Comment: @Pow: aha, okay - take an element (x,y,z) on your plane. Supposing $c \neq 0$, we can more helpfully write this as (x,y,$\frac{-ax-by}{c}$). Now it suffices for you to find r and s (in terms of a, b, c, x and y) such that r(b,-a,0) + s(0,c,-b) = (x,y,$\frac{-ax-by}{c}$) - shouldn't be too hard. (Then of course you have to deal with the case $c = 0$...) :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks!